# Is looping inside class possible?

Tags: python, loops, class, oop, while-loop

I already asked this question, but I guess I have to clarify, and for that I apologize. Let us consider the most mundane, ultimate noobie while loop.

```py
    max_count = 4
    count = 0
    while count < max_count:
        print(count)
        count += 1
```

It obviously prints 0 1 2 3. So, I naively reckon, mayhaps we do it OOP style, as below.

```py
    class Foo:
        def __init__(self, max_count):
            self.max_count = max_count
            self.count = 0
    
        def loop(self):
            while self.count < self.max_count:
                print(self.count)
                self.count += 1
    
    A = Foo(4).loop()
```

and again it obligingly spurts out 0 1 2 3. But then I get greedy and say to myself, what if I don't want to print the data, but just retrieve them for something higher and nobler, say doing a few nested loops. So instead of print in the loop method I do a return as below.

```py
    class Foo:
        def __init__(self, max_count):
            self.max_count = max_count
            self.count = 0
    
        def loop(self):
            while self.count < self.max_count:
                return self.count
                self.count += 1
    
    A = Foo(4).loop()
    print(A)
```

And the powers that be reward me with a nice, flat 0. In my uneducated lingua, I  would say that the class is 'choking' the loop. Please, enlighten me: Is it even possible to loop inside a class or not. And if yes, please point me in the right direction and I will do the digging. BTW, I would like it to be in OOP mode, since what I really intend to is control a number of stepper motors concurrently. If I try to do it procedurally, that will bring back to my 1988 Pascal, Fortran 77 days, and that is a chalice from which I do not want to drink again. I thank you in advance kind comrades.

Comment: You may want to read https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

Answer (score 1):

The reason your result is `0` is because you are returning from the `loop` function before incrementing the value. I assume you intended to print the value? or maybe return it *after* the loop?

This code:

```py
while self.count<self.max_count:
    return self.count
    self.count+=1
```

Should be:

```py
while self.count < self.max_count:
    self.count+=1
return self.count
```

Comment: Thanx Ian. BTW, any reason the return is not indented?

Comment: Actually, I definitely do not want to print the results. What i would like to do ultimately is have a bunch of nested loops (with a couple of if statement thrown in for good measure) and all this inside the class. You deem is doable?

Comment: @TheodorosNikoleris in python, everything that is indented is part of the while loop. Since you dont want to return EVERY TIME the loop runs, but AFTER the loop, the return may not be indented.